# c# Live Chart Line Different Color

Tags: c#, livecharts

I have two time series, first is every daily price and second is some day's price. I want to one line but I awant to paint the some day's price. I found that link but I don't understand how to do it.

link: https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/issues/162#issuecomment-232700608

my code:

```cs
var dayConfig = Mappers.Xy < ChartModel > ().X(dayModel =>dayModel.DateTime.Ticks).Y(dayModel =>dayModel.Value);

SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection(dayConfig) {
  new LineSeries {
    Title = hisse1,
    Values = ChartModelList.AsChartValues(),
  },
};

Formatter = value =>new DateTime((long) value).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define series colors either in XAML or in your data model.

**XAML**

```
<wpf:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}>
  <wpf:CartesianChart.SeriesColors>
    <wpf:ColorsCollection>
      <Color>Yellow</Color>
      <Color>Green</Color>
    </wpf:ColorsCollection>
  </wpf:CartesianChart.SeriesColors>
</wpf:CartesianChart>
```

**C#**

You can generally set attributes like `Fill`, `Stroke`, `StrokeThickness` and `StrokeDashArray` to customize the series' color.

```
// Draw a sine
var chartValues = new ChartValues<Point>();
for (int x = 0; x < 361; x++)
{
  var point = new Point() {X = x, Y = Math.Sin(x * Math.PI / 180)};
  chartValues.Add(point);
}

this.SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
{
  // Set the line series color directly on the series object
  new LineSeries
  {
    Title = "Yellow Series",
    Values = chartValues,
    Fill = Brushes.Yellow,
    Stroke = Brushes.Blue
  },
  // Or use a Mapper which offers more flexibility e.g. allowing conditional coloring
  new LineSeries
  {
    Title = "Mixed Color Series",
    Configuration = new CartesianMapper<Point>()
      .X(point => point.X)
      .Y(point => point.Y)
      .Stroke(point => point.X > 50 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen)
      .Fill(point => point.X > 50 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen),
    Values = chartValues
  }
};
```